# Цвет отдельных слов

Tags: c#, winforms

Привет всем!

Можно ли изменить цвет одного слова в TextBox? Пример, чтобы  слово print было синим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо оверрайдить пайнт либо использовать другой контрол. Стандартно текст бокс не умеет отрисовывать текст разными цветами (только один для всего текста в контроле)

Из возможных и самых простых кандидатов на замену с разноцветной раскраской текста - RichTextBox

Comment: а,xml можно подлключить?

Comment: А что значит - "подключить xml" ?

Comment: Ну вот я дето видел что к textbox1 подключили .xml файл и в нём было указан цвет каких слов нада изменить.

Comment: Скотчем что ли приклеили к монитору? :-) Стандартный класс TextBox не умеет так. RichTextBox тоже не имплементирует функционал позволяющий задавать ему в качестве свойства xml файл с набором слов. Возможно вы выдели какой то другой класс контрола?

Comment: Может ошибся.